# Laravel edit existing pdf

Tags: laravel, pdf, edit

I don't know how to edit an existing pdf file with Laravel.

I have found many plugin for create PDF but no one help me in my problem.

Can anyone know how to do it?

This is what I have tried so far

```php
$pdf->AddPage();
$source = $pdf->setSourceFile(asset("assets/images/coupon/source/coupon.pdf"));
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 90);
$pdf->SetXY(40, 0); // Doesn't work
$pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text'); // Doesn't work
$pdf->Output(); // Doesn't work
```

Comment: `writeHTMLCell` is not a `FPDF` method. Where does this method come from? Furthermore what I saw from your code: You don't want to edit a PDF - you just want to create a new one? You are not referencing an existing PDF file, because you are missing `$pdf->setSourceFile('PATH/TO/SOURCEFILE')`

Comment: It's not my totally code I have the SetSourceFile, ImportPage,UseTemplate but SetXY and Write And Output doesn't work ...

Comment: Ok it work ! the source wasn't good ! thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad you got it running!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is **no built-in way** for Laravel to **edit PDFs**. You can of course use external libs, such as [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) with the [FPDI](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/) extension to modify PDFs - the result is a new PDF file. There is also a paid lib [PDFlib](http://www.pdflib.com/en/) that is capable of editing PDFs.

To install FPDF + FPDI in Laravel you just need to run:

```sh
composer require setasign/fpdf && composer require setasign/fpdi
```

This will install the base FPDF lib + the extension FPDI. Afterwards you can create a new instance and edit your PDF with:

```php
$pdf = new \FPDI();
$pdf->setSourceFile('PATH/TO/SOURCEFILE');
```

Please make yourself comfortable with the [FPDI documentation](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/the-fpdi-class/)

**Update:**
With FPDI you *cannot* directly edit a PDF file. All FPDI does is extracting content from a given PDF file into a reusable format - the result is a complete new PDF. This information can also be found in the [FAQ](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-i-edit-a-pdf-document-with-fpdi/#question-202) of FPDI.

Comment: Thanks but I already have found a Fpdf lib for Laravel but no FPDI ... How can I use it ?

Comment: What Laravel version do you use? How do you use FPDF - can you show some code?

Comment: Thanks I use Laravel 5 and I want to open a pdf and add the user name in Just that

Comment: I got one error 'Call to undefined method FPDI::writeHTMLCell()' I add the code

Comment: Please update this answer, it is wrong! You cannot edit a PDF with FPDI but you can "only" import single pages of an existing PDF document into a reusable structure with it. This information can also be found in the [FAQ](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-i-edit-a-pdf-document-with-fpdi/#question-202) of FPDI.

Comment: Thanks @Setasign for making this clear. I updated my post.