# how to edit pdf file in laravel 5.6. Save same file if not edited or another selected file?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update the file in laravel 5.6. But the file is not showing in edit.blade.php. When i click update button the file goes null..

editfile.blade.php

```
<div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Publication File</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="file" name="publication_file" id="publication_file" value=" {{ $publicationDetails->publication_file }}"> <span> {{ $publicationDetails->publication_file }} </span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Update function in controller

```
 if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $data = $request->all();

        Publication::where(['publication_id'=>$publication_id])->update(['publication_title' => $data['publication_title'],'publication_type'=>$data['publication_type'],'publication_file'=>$data['publication_file']]);
       return redirect('/admin/view-publication')->with('flash_message_success','Publication Updated Successfully..');
    }
    $publicationDetails = Publication::where(['publication_id'=>$publication_id])->first();
    return view('admin.publication.edit_publication')->with(compact('publicationDetails'));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel edit existing pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209558/laravel-edit-existing-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way for Laravel to edit PDFs. You can of course use external libs, such as [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) with the FPDI extension to modify PDFs or [tcpdf](https://tcpdf.org/examples/) to write in predefined file, or u can create pdf based on html file - the result is a new PDF file. There is also a paid lib PDFlib that is capable of editing PDFs.

Comment: You have to store file temporary at server and then edit that file using external library.. you can replace existing file or [delete](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#deleting-files) existing file ... and save new edited copy of file.

Comment: Dear, copying existing answers isn't a great way to gain rep (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37210137/5879295)