# Add watermark to PDF in laravel

Tags: laravel

I upload PDFs using File/browse option from frontend and As I Upload, I want to have a watermark uploaded to those PDFs automatically. Below is a sample code for upload pdf in Store function of the controller

```
if ($request->hasFile('qpid')) {
        $paperuploads = $request->file('qpid');
        foreach ($paperuploads as $paperupload){
        $paperuploadfilename = 'QP_'. time() . '.' . $paperupload->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/storage/papers');
```

Is there any way to dynamically add watermark to PDF? Thanks

Comment: does that help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37210137/4258328

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ChristopheHubert - I tried this but was facing lot of issues with different PDF sizes. Finally was able to do it via MarkPDF

Comment: Glad you managed and thanks for sharing your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For benefit of others, I got this solved by using following Github repository:

https://github.com/ajaxray/markpdf

Then using symfony process to call MarkPDF and thereby getting this implemented.

Comment: would appreciate if you share the code of how you successfully implemented it on laravel